# Sorting a ggplot axis' factor according to another factor's levels

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have successfully created a boxplot that displays the score of several neighborhoods of a city and have coloured them according to the district they belong to. The result looks like this:

```r
library(ggplot2)

df = read.csv("http://pastebin.com/raw/rpPLwSXn")

ggplot(df, aes(x = neighbourhood, y = score, fill = district)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  ggtitle("Neighbourhoods' score") +
  labs(x = "Neighbourhoods", y = "Score", fill = "District") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))
```

[image]

It looks quite well despite the fact that instead of sorting the neighborhoods on the x axis alphabetically (`neighbourhood` column on the dataframe) I would like them to be sorted according to the discrict they belong to (`district` variable on the dataframe)

I've read that I could use `factor` to relevel the values on `neighbourhood` column, but haven't succeeded with that since the vector lenght is different (there are less districts than neighbourhoods)

Comment: So, for neighbourhoods that are in the same district, how do you want them ordered?

Comment: First District in alphabetical order, then neighbourhoouds alphabetically, I'll update description as soon as I get in front of a keyboard

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like the facet idea in Ulrik's answer - that will probably be the nicest visualization. To order the factor levels of the `neighbourhood` column the easiest way is probably like this:

```
# order the data frame as desired
df = df[order(df$district, df$neighbourhood), ]
# set the neighbourhood levels in the order the occur in the data frame
df$neighbourhood = factor(df$neighbourhood, levels = unique(df$neighbourhood))
```

After the levels are in the order you want, the axis will follow.

Answer (score 2):

I would faceted on the district along the lines of facet_wrap(~ district)

See ?facet_grid and ?facet_wrap

Comment: Can you show complete code? My naive interpretation of your suggestion was that you wanted to add `+facet_grid(~district)` which was an abysmal fail. At the moment this appears more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but faceting is not what I am looking for

Comment: adding `facet_grid(~ district, scales = "free_x", space = "free")` works pretty well - some of the district names don't quite fit in the facet strips, but that could be worked around with line breaks or something.